# My batchfile prompt keeps catching all answers as the first label

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe

My batch file always returns PLUGINS instead of going to the desired place when I press any number between those prompted. What could the problem stem from?

> @echo off ECHO Control Panel initialized.
>
> :BEGIN
>
> CHOICE /N /C:1234 /M "PICK A NUMBER (1(PLUGINS), 2(MOTD), 3(LOGS),
>   4(END)"%1
>
> IF %%ERRORLEVEL ==1 GOTO ONE
>
> IF %%ERRORLEVEL ==2 GOTO TWO
>
> IF %%ERRORLEVEL ==3 GOTO THREE
>
> IF %%ERRORLEVEL ==4 GOTO END
>
> :ONE
>
> ECHO PLUGINS
>
> explorer \\192.168.1.16\Server\Server-Dedicated Slightly\Here is the
>   Actual Server dir\plugins
>
> GOTO BEGIN
>
> :TWO
>
> ECHO MOTD
>
> notepad \\192.168.1.16\Server\Server-Dedicated Slightly\Here is the
>   Actual Server dir\plugins\Essentials\motd
>
> GOTO BEGIN
>
> :THREE
>
> ECHO LOGS
>
> notepad \\192.168.1.16\Server\Server-Dedicated Slightly\Here is the
>   Actual Server  dir\server
>
> GOTO BEGIN
>
> :END
>
> PAUSE

Comment: Shouldn't it be `%ERRORLEVEL%` instead of `%%ERRORLEVEL`? (And maybe `EQU` instead of `==`?)

Comment: Ahh yes thank you I forgot %% was for only one character.

Answer (score 0):

Three problems:

1. ERRORLEVEL checks for the given value, or above, so you have to order them from HIGH to LOW, not the other way around
2. it's ERRORLEVEL, not %%ERRORLEVEL
3. it's just ERRORLEVEL num

So, in short, you'll get

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO END 
...
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ONE
```

Comment: Thanks, with a bit of clearing up thanks to your suggestions it works now. I suppose it wasn't hard to tell I'm new at this.

Comment: Great :-)  Batch is a bit odd sometimes, indeed.

Comment: You don't always need to list the numbers from largest to smallest. 

You can add EQU (equ) or == if you want to. It doesn't make much difference.

Comment: @ProfPickle I was merely citing [the doco](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/if.mspx?mfr=true).  If you use the simple traditional format as I suggest they do have to be in descending order, but it will work everywhere, from the oldest DOS to the current version of Windows.  `%errorlevel%` was introduced later.